# Insert new items above the current top row in FlatList without inflicting automatic scrollToTop

Tags: react-native

How can you push new items to the data of a FlatList yet keep the top row before the update visible after the update and the FlatList should not scroll to top to the new items pushed above?

**Problem**: When updating a component state with new data that needs to render rows above the current top row the FlatList will sort of re-render and start the contentOffset.y from the top all over again.

**Example**: Let's say I have the following data for the initial load of the FlatList

```
this.state = {
    data: [
        {title: '2019-03-10', events: []}, 
        {title: '2019-03-11', events: []}, 
        {title: '2019-03-12', events: []}, 
    ]

}
```

and the top visible row is the item with the title of '2019-03-10' then let's say I *pull to refresh* and wanna push this new data ->

```
const newData = [
    {title: '2019-03-07', events: []}, 
    {title: '2019-03-08', events: []}, 
    {title: '2019-03-09', events: []}, 
]
```

into the state like so ->

```
this.setState({
    data: this.mergeAndSortData(this.state.data, newData)
})
```

now my data is sorted by ascending date of the title so I'm adding the new data above the data of the current top visible row and the indexes of all rows change and that forces the FlatList to reload and by so resetting the contentOffset.y to 0 and the current top visible row will be titled '2019-03-07'.

**Preferred**: I would like a way to update with new data and keep the previous top visible row where it is.

One more condition that makes this even more complex is the fact that each row can be any given height there is no set height for all rows.

**Tried**: Here is what I tried so far

1. Setting the initialScrollIndex state after the component update.

   ***Result***: Didn't do anything, I guess initialScrollIndex only works on initial load not even after reloading of the FlatList data.
2. Getting the current scroll offset y before the update and after
   the update calculating how much-estimated height the FlatList will
   need to add for new items and calling this.list.scrollToOffset of
   that estimated height.

   ***Result*** : Had to put the scroll to function in a timeout for it to do 
   anything and it resulted in a flickering of the FlatList after each update and 
   scroll to. (Was the only thing that worked but not usable).
3. Using scrollToIndex and also passing an
   estimated height based on the data of the item to getItemLayout prop
   on the FlatList.

   ***Result***: Didn't move till the intended row.
4. Calling in a while loop scrollToOffset and
   incrementally scrolling down the FlatList till I would get in the
   onViewableItemsChanged callback that the row I want visible came
   into view.

   ***Result***: The onViewableItemsChanged didn't get called while in
   the while loop and I couldn't stop resulting in infinite loop.
5. Setting a ref for each row item and after updating new data measuring the row's offset I want visible via the ref and scrolling to that offset.

   ***Result***: For some reason the y offset of the previous row was always much less than the actual offset, perhaps because I was measuring to close to the re-layout or somthing else I missed.

Here is some of my code ->

```
const isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 80
  return (
    layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom
  )
}

const isCloseToTop = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
  const paddingToTop = 80
  return contentOffset.y <= paddingToTop
}

var initMonthRange = {
  start: moment()
    .startOf('month')
    .startOf('week')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    .toString(),
  end: moment()
    .endOf('month')
    .endOf('week')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    .toString()
}

export default class AllEventsView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      events: this.getGroupedEvents(props),
      isFetchingFuture: false,
      isFetchingPast: false,
      isFetching: false,
      currentMonth: moment(),
    }

    this.offset = 0
    this.currentVisibleIndex = 0
    this.currentVisibleDate = this.getFirstDate()
    this.scrollToRef = this.strToMoment(this.currentVisibleDate)

    this.heights = []

    this._onViewableItemsChanged = this._onViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)

    // this.viewabilityConfig = {
    //   waitForInteraction: true,
    //   viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95
    // }

    this.itemsRefs = {}

    this.isDynamicScroll = false
  }

  itemHeightForData(item) {
    let output = 0

    if (item) {
      let titleHeight = 45
      let paddingBottom = 25 // list cont
      let marginBottom = 10 // event cont
      let rowHeight = 102

      // 82 without row height

      var { data } = item
      if (data) {
        data.map(value => {
          output += rowHeight // + marginBottom
        })
      }

      output += titleHeight + paddingBottom + marginBottom
    } else {
      output = 182
    }

    return output
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps !== this.props) {
      var { loading, events } = nextProps
      if (
        events &&
        events.length > 0 &&
        !_.isEqual(events, this.props.events) &&
        !_.isEqual(events, this.state.events)
      ) {
        this.setState({
          isFetching: loading,
          isFetchingPast: loading,
          isFetchingFuture: loading
        })

        this.updateEvents(nextProps)
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    var { events } = prevState
    if (events && !_.isEqual(events, this.state.events)) {
      if (
        this.strToMoment(events[0].title).isAfter(this.state.events[0].title)
      ) {
        // new data is in the passed
        this.scrollToSelected()
        // this.scrollTillCurrentDate()
        //this.scrollToDate()
      } else if (
        this.strToMoment(events[events.length - 1].title).isBefore(
          this.state.events[this.state.events.length - 1].title
        )
      ) {
        // new data is in the future
      }
    }
  }

  momentToStr(date) {
    return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString()
  }

  strToMoment(str) {
    return moment(str)
  }

  getDateForIndex(index) {
    var output

    var events = this.state.events
    if (events && events.length > index) {
      output = events[index].title
    }

    return output
  }

  getIndexForDate(date, newEvents) {
    var output

    var array = newEvents || this.state.events

    if (array) {
      array.map((value, index) => {
        var { title } = value
        if (title === date) {
          output = index
        }
      })
    }

    return output
  }

  getFirstDate() {
    return this.strToMoment(this.getDateForIndex(0))
  }

  getCurrentIndex(newEvents) {
    var index = this.getIndexForDate(
      this.momentToStr(this.currentVisibleDate),
      newEvents
    )

    return index
  }

  updateScrollTo(newEvents) {
    var index = this.getIndexForDate(
      this.momentToStr(this.currentVisibleDate),
      newEvents
    )
    if (index > -1) {
      this.currentVisibleIndex = index

      this.setState({
        currentVisibleIndex: index
      })
    }

    //this.scrollToRef = this.strToMoment(this.currentVisibleDate)
  }

  updateEvents(nextProps) {
    var newEvents = this.getGroupedEvents(nextProps)

    var index = this.getCurrentIndex(newEvents)
    this.currentVisibleIndex = index

    this.setState({
      currentVisibleIndex: index,
      events: newEvents
    })
  }

  /*scrollToDate() {
    var date = this.momentToStr(this.currentVisibleDate)
    if (date) {
      if (this.itemsRefs[date]) {
        this.itemsRefs[date].measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
          console.log(ox, oy, width, height, px, py)

          this.list.scrollToOffset({
            offset: py + oy + height,
            animated: false
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }*/

  getOffset() {
    let scrollPosition = 0
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.currentVisibleIndex; i++) {
      var itemHeight = this.itemHeightForData(this.state.events[i])
      scrollPosition += itemHeight
    }

    return scrollPosition
  }

  scrollToSelected() {
    if (this.list) {
      this.isDynamicScroll = true
      var scrollPosition = this.getOffset()

      setTimeout(() => {
         this.list.scrollToOffset({
           offset: scrollPosition,
           animated: false
         })
        this.isDynamicScroll = false
      }, 80)
    }
  }

  // scrollTillCurrentDate() {
  //   if (this.list) {
  //     var maxOffset = this.getOffset() * 2
  //     var initOffset = 182
  //     // var beforeDate = moment(this.currentVisibleDate).isBefore(
  //     //   this.state.clonedDate
  //     // )
  //     while (initOffset < maxOffset) {
  //       this.list.scrollToOffset({
  //         offset: initOffset,
  //         animated: false
  //       })

  //       initOffset += 182
  //     }
  //   }
  // }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.title

  onDayPress(day) {
    this.setState({
      currentMonth: day
    })

    var { onDayPress } = this.props
    if (onDayPress) {
      onDayPress(day)
    }
  }

  fetchPast() {
    if (!this.state.isFetching) {
      var { setStartDate } = this.props
      if (setStartDate) {
        var newStart = moment(initMonthRange.start)
          .subtract(1, 'month')
          .startOf('month')
          .startOf('week')

        var newDay = {
          dateString: newStart
        }

        this.onDayPress(newDay)

        if (newStart.isBefore(initMonthRange.start)) {
          initMonthRange.start = newStart
          setStartDate(newStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString())
        }
      }
    }
  }

  fetchFuture() {
    if (!this.state.isFetching) {
      var { setEndDate } = this.props
      if (setEndDate) {
        var newEnd = moment(initMonthRange.end)
          .add(1, 'month')
          .endOf('month')
          .endOf('week')

        var newDay = {
          dateString: newEnd
        }

        this.onDayPress(newDay)

        if (newEnd.isAfter(initMonthRange.end)) {
          initMonthRange.end = newEnd
          setEndDate(newEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString())
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setVisibleIndex(index, key) {
    var output = 0

    if (index) {
      output = index
    } else {
      var tryIndex = this.getIndexForDate(key)
      if (tryIndex) {
        output = tryIndex
      }
    }

    return output
  }

  setVisibleDate(key, item) {
    return moment(key || item.title)
  }

  _onViewableItemsChanged({ viewableItems, changed }) {
    if (viewableItems && viewableItems.length > 0) {
      var { isViewable, index, key, item } = viewableItems[0]
      if (isViewable) {
        var visibleIndex = this.setVisibleIndex(index, key)
        var visibleDay = this.setVisibleDate(key, item)

        this.currentVisibleDate = visibleDay
      }
    }
  }

  _onScroll(event) {
    var currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
    var direction = currentOffset > this.offset ? 'down' : 'up'
    this.offset = currentOffset

    if (!this.isDynamicScroll) {
      if (direction === 'up' && isCloseToTop(event.nativeEvent)) {
        this.fetchPast()
      }

      if (direction === 'down' && isCloseToBottom(event.nativeEvent)) {
        this.fetchFuture()
      }
    }
  }

  onListTouch() {
    this.isDynamicScroll = false
  }

  getHeightForIndex(data, index) {
    // return this.heights[index] not usable for preloaded rows
    return this.itemHeightForData(this.state.events[index])
  }

  onRowLayoutChange(ind, event) {
    this.heights[ind] = event.nativeEvent.layout.height
  }

  _renderItem({ item, index }) {
    var { title, data } = item

    return (
      <View
        onLayout={this.onRowLayoutChange.bind(this, index)}
        ref={i => (this.itemsRefs[title] = i)}
      >
        <EventsListView
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          error={this.props.error}
          loading={this.props.loading}
          events={data}
          selectedDate={title}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  getGroupedEvents(props) {
    var output = []

    var groupedEvents = {}

    var { events } = props || this.props
    if (events) {
      events.map(value => {
        var { startDate } = value
        if (startDate) {
          var dateKey = moment(startDate)
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            .toString()

          var containingEvents = []
          if (groupedEvents[dateKey]) {
            if (groupedEvents[dateKey] && groupedEvents[dateKey].length > 0) {
              containingEvents = groupedEvents[dateKey]
            }
          }

          containingEvents.push(value)

          groupedEvents[dateKey] = containingEvents
        }
      })
    }

    Object.keys(groupedEvents)
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          moment(a)
            .toDate()
            .getTime() -
          moment(b)
            .toDate()
            .getTime()
        )
      })
      .map(key => {
        output.push({ title: key, data: groupedEvents[key] })
      })

    return output
  }

  _renderSeparator = () => <View style={style.itemSeparator} />

  render() {
    var { loading } = this.props

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.state.events && this.state.events.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            ref={c => (this.list = c)}
            data={this.state.events}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
            onScroll={this._onScroll.bind(this)}
            onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={200}
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
              length: this.getHeightForIndex(index),
              offset: this.getHeightForIndex(index) * index,
              index
            })}
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
              this.onListTouch()
              return false
            }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
          />
        ) : (
          <View
            style={[
              style.nothingYet,
              globalStyle.shadowedRowView,
              { marginRight: 0, marginLeft: 0 }
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={style.nothingYetText}>{`${
              loading ? 'Loading' : 'Nothing Yet'
            }...`}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I want an efficient way to scroll to the previous visible top row before the new updates.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I was gonna be using https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars Agenda view but they don't support scrolling up to show new items fetched I guess for the same issues I'm having, yet in native programming iOS & Android, this is fairly simple to do e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows to add sepcific data to specific index or simply https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorowatindexpath to scroll to the wanted visible row.